# Smoothness of (generalized) eigenspaces, or existence of smooth vectors in the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been investigating the solvability of some parametric ODE for smooth solutions in the parameters. After some transformations, the question is
re-formulated as follows.

Consider a parameter-dependent matrix
$J_{\alpha}: \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which has a
non-semisimple double-zero eigenvalue (algebraic multiplicity two but
geometric multiplicity one) at some critical parameter value, say, $\alpha=0$.
Assume that $J_\alpha$ is sufficiently smooth in $\alpha$.

Of course, we can find the (generalized) real eigenvectors of $J_0$ associated
with zero eigenvalue,
\begin{equation}
J_0x=0,~~J_0y=x.
\end{equation}

Now, let us define continuous fucntions $\lambda_1(\alpha)$ and $\lambda_2(\alpha)$ to be the parameter-dependent eigenvalues
of $J_\alpha$ s.t. $\lambda_1(0)=\lambda_2(0)=0$;
and define linearly independent $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{C}^n$ (if possible) s.t.
$J_\alpha v_1=\lambda_1 v_1$, $J_\alpha v_2=\lambda_2 v_2$.
In a neighborhood of $\alpha=0$, consider the two dimensional
subspace
\begin{equation}
V(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\colon=
\begin{cases}
\text{the generalized eigenspace to $\lambda$},
     ~\text{if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$, nonsemisimple;}\\
\text{span}\{v_1, v_2\}\,\cap\,\mathbb{R}^n,
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Question:
Can we construct a smooth vector $v(\alpha)\in V(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ s.t.
$v(0)=y$?
Or more generally, is this subspace $V$ smooth in $\alpha$?

I believe this is true but I'm not sure how to prove it.
I searched related questions, but it seems that most of them are about
the continuity or smoothness of the eigenvectors, which is much stronger
and has few nice conclusions.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake but I want to find $v(\alpha)$ in $V(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. Mistake edited and corrected.